# How can I calculate the integral $ \int_{\left| z \right| = r} \frac{dz}{(z-a)^n(z-b)^n} $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How can I calculate the integral?
$$
\int_{\left| z \right| = r} \frac{dz}{(z-a)^n(z-b)^n} 
$$ 
for $ \left| a \right| < r < \left| b \right|$ and $ m, n > 1$

I tried to use the cauchy integral forula but given the variable m and n, there should be probably another aproach?

Comment: Why the question in the title does not match the one in the remainder?

Comment: Use the residue theorem. For the integral in the body, the change of variables $w = z - a$ is helpful in computing the residue at $a$.

Comment: Why is the title different from the body?

Comment: @Bython the integrand reads $\frac{1}{(z - a)^\color{red}{n}(z - b)^\color{red}{n}}$, but is that what you wanted? I see that you mentioned $m$, but $m$ is not present in the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|a| < r < |b|$, the function $f(z) := 1/(z - b)^n$ is analytic inside and on the circle $|z| = r$, and $a$ lies inside $|z| = r$. Hence, by Cauchy's differentiation formula,

\begin{align}\int_{|z| = r} \frac{1}{(z - a)^n (z - b)^n}\, dz &= \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(a)\\
&= \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n(n+1)\cdots (2n-2)}{(a - b)^{2n-1}}\\
&= (-1)^{n-1} \binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{2\pi i}{(a - b)^{2n-1}}.
\end{align}